# WebService com PHP + SOAP - Duvida com o retorno

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Estou usando um *webservice* para realizar envios de arquivo da portaria CAT52

*WebService*: https://www.nfp.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/arquivocf.asmx?WSDL

Está fazendo a comunicação tudo normal (pelo menos eu acho) porém está vindo um retorno que não estou conseguindo entender

Retorno através do `vardump`

> object(stdClass)[9]   public 'EnviarResult' => string '999|String
>   reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s'
>   (length=74)

Pela mensagem é string que não foi instanciada, parâmetro 's', porém não tenho esse parâmetro.

Segue o código para que possam me ajudar

```
    $headerBody = array('CNPJ' => $this->getCnpj(),
                            'CategoriaUsuario' => $this->getCategoriaUsuario(),
                            'Senha' => $this->getSenha(),
                            'Usuario' => $this->getUsuario());


    $header = new SOAPHeader($this->getXmlns(), 'Autenticacao', $headerBody);

    $this->cliente = new SoapClient( $this->getWsdlUrl(), array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
    $this->cliente->__setSOAPHeaders($header);

$filename = new SoapParam($arquivoNome, 'NomeArquivo');
        $content = new SoapParam(utf8_encode($arquivoConteudo), 'ConteudoArquivo');
        $tipoenvio = new SoapParam($envioNormal, 'EnvioNormal');
        $obs = new SoapParam($observacoes, 'Observacoes');

        //$resEnvio = $this->cliente->__soapCall('Enviar', $token);
        $resEnvio = $this->cliente->Enviar($filename, $content, $tipoenvio, $obs);
        var_dump($resEnvio);
```

Comment: O que está sendo setado na chave EnviarResult?

Comment: o EnviarResult é o retorno, não setei nada